# Nutiteq Maps JavaMe obfuscation error

Tags: netbeans, java-me, maps, obfuscation, proguard

I have a midlet that uses Nutiteq maps and I developed it in Netbeans.  I added the library jar to the project.  Everything works fine.  The problem is when I obfuscate, I get this:

```
Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.microedition.media.control.ToneControl]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.microedition.media.control.VolumeControl]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.microedition.media.Control]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.microedition.media.Controllable]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.microedition.media.Manager]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.microedition.media.MediaException]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.microedition.media.Player]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.microedition.media.PlayerListener]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.microedition.media.protocol.DataSource]
Note: there were 9 duplicate class definitions.
Warning: com.nutiteq.fs.MotoFileSystem: can't find referenced class com.motorola.io.FileConnection
Warning: com.nutiteq.fs.MotoFileSystem: can't find referenced class com.motorola.io.FileSystemRegistry
Warning: com.nutiteq.fs.MotoFileSystem: can't find referenced class com.motorola.io.FileSystemRegistry
Warning: com.nutiteq.fs.MotoFileSystem: can't find referenced class com.motorola.io.FileConnection
Warning: com.nutiteq.fs.MotoFileSystem: can't find referenced class com.motorola.io.FileConnection
Warning: com.nutiteq.fs.MotoFileSystem: can't find referenced class com.motorola.io.FileConnection
Warning: com.nutiteq.fs.MotoFileSystem: can't find referenced class com.motorola.io.FileConnection
Warning: com.nutiteq.fs.IDENFileSystem: can't find referenced class com.motorola.io.file.FileConnection
Warning: com.nutiteq.fs.IDENFileSystem: can't find referenced class com.motorola.io.file.FileConnection
Warning: com.nutiteq.fs.IDENFileSystem: can't find referenced class com.motorola.io.file.FileConnection
Warning: com.nutiteq.fs.IDENFileSystem: can't find referenced class com.motorola.io.file.FileConnection
Warning: com.nutiteq.fs.IDENFileSystem: can't find referenced class com.motorola.io.file.FileConnection
Note: com.sun.lwuit.impl.midp.GameCanvasImplementation: can't find dynamically referenced class com.siemens.mp.game.Light
Note: com.sun.lwuit.impl.midp.GameCanvasImplementation: can't find dynamically referenced class com.motorola.phonebook.PhoneBookRecord
Note: com.sun.lwuit.impl.midp.GameCanvasImplementation: can't find dynamically referenced class com.nokia.mid.ui.FullCanvas
Note: com.sun.lwuit.impl.midp.GameCanvasImplementation: can't find dynamically referenced class net.rim.device.api.system.Application
Note: com.sun.lwuit.impl.midp.GameCanvasImplementation: can't find dynamically referenced class com.mot.iden.util.Base64
Note: com.sun.lwuit.impl.midp.GameCanvasImplementation: can't find dynamically referenced class mmpp.media.MediaPlayer
  You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
Warning: there were 12 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
     You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars'),
     or perhaps the '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses' option.
Error: Please correct the above warnings first.
Note: there were 6 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
```

I'm usign lwuit library but I haven't have any problem until I include the map library.

I did what this page says: http://www.nutiteq.com/j2me-maps-forum

And now I get this:

```
.
.
.
te: duplicate definition of library class [com.sun.cldc.i18n.uclc.DefaultCaseConverter]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [com.sun.j2mews.xml.rpc.OperationImpl]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [com.sun.j2mews.xml.rpc.SOAPDecoder]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [com.sun.j2mews.xml.rpc.SOAPEncoder]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [com.sun.ukit.jaxp.Parser]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [com.sun.ukit.jaxp.ParserFactory]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [com.sun.ukit.jaxp.ReaderUTF16]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [com.sun.ukit.jaxp.ReaderUTF8]
Note: there were 564 duplicate class definitions.
Note: com.sun.lwuit.impl.midp.GameCanvasImplementation: can't find dynamically referenced class com.motorola.phonebook.PhoneBookRecord
Note: com.sun.lwuit.impl.midp.GameCanvasImplementation: can't find dynamically referenced class mmpp.media.MediaPlayer
Note: there were 2 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
  You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
Unexpected error while evaluating instruction:
Class       = [a]
Method      = [a$623fafe4(Ljava/lang/String;CI)[Ljava/lang/String;]
Instruction = [85] iload_3 v3
Exception   = [java.lang.NullPointerException] (null)
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
Class       = [a]
Method      = [a$623fafe4(Ljava/lang/String;CI)[Ljava/lang/String;]
Exception   = [java.lang.NullPointerException] (null)
Error: null
```

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate classes are generally harmless, but they indicate that your configuration specifies -libraryjars options with jars that contain the same classes twice. It would be cleaner to remove those duplicates. Otherwise you can specify -dontnote to suppress these notes.

The unexpected error is a bug in ProGuard. You should make sure that you are using the latest version (4.8 or 4.9 beta at this time). If the problem remains, you should report it on the [ProGuard website](http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/) or mail it to me, with a small project that allows me to reproduce the problem. You can probably work around it by switching off optimization with -dontoptimize.